# Connecting to ms access database using php

Tags: php

Am getting could not find file error while connecting to ms access database using php.

and my code is

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "msdb\jcdbone.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

How to connect to ms access database using php? help me with small example.  ....Thanks in advance

Comment: As a test - remove the the `$db = new PDO...` line. Do you still get the same error? Is it your "Could not find database file." error? If so check `die($dbName);` and make sure your path looks ok and the file is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an could not find file error then that means your path is probably wrong.

Try adding

```
echo $dbName;
```

right below

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "msdb\jcdbone.mdb";
```

and then compare that path to the actual location of your jcdbone.mdb file and then adjust accordingly.

A quick Google shows you probably picked this example up from a sitepoint article. The code sample should be good -- you just need to make sure the path is correct.